# Will full memory barriers around std::shared_ptr's use_count() make it a reliable counter?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, memory-barriers, reference-counting

I'm implementing a thread-safe "lazy-synchronized" Set as a linked list of nodes connected by shared_ptr's. The algorithm is from "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming". I'm adding an `is_empty()` function that needs to be linearizable with the existing functions: `contains(), add(), remove()`. In the code below, you can see  `remove`  is a 2 step process. First it "lazy" marks the node by setting `marked = nullptr`, then it physically moves the linked list `next` pointers.

Modified classes to support is_empty()

```cpp
template <class T>
class LazySet : public Set<T> {
    public:
      LazySet ();
      bool contains (const T&) const;
      bool is_empty ()         const;
      bool add      (const T&);
      bool remove   (const T&);
    private:
      bool validate(const std::shared_ptr<Node>&, const std::shared_ptr<Node>&);
      class Node;
      std::shared_ptr<Node> head;
      std::shared_ptr<bool> counter; //note: type is unimportant, will never change true/fase
};

template <class T>
class LazySet<T>::Node {
    public:
      Node ();
      Node (const T&);
      T key;
      std::shared_ptr<bool> marked; //assume initialized to = LazySet.counter
                                    // nullptr means it's marked; otherwise unmarked
      std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
      std::mutex mtx;
};
```

Relevant modified methods to support is_empty

```cpp
template <class T>
bool LazySet<T>::remove(const T& k) {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> pred;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> curr;
    while (true) {
        pred = head;
        curr = atomic_load(&(head->next));
        //Find window where key should be in sorted list
        while ((curr) && (curr->key < k)) {
            pred = atomic_load(&curr);
            curr = atomic_load(&(curr->next));
        }
        //Aquire locks on the window, left to right locking prevents deadlock
        (pred->mtx).lock();
        if (curr) { //only lock if not nullptr
            (curr->mtx).lock();
        }
        //Ensure window didn't change before locking, and then remove
        if (validate(pred, curr)) {
            if (!curr) { //key doesn't exist, do nothing
                //## unimportant ##
            } else { //key exists, remove it
                atomic_store(&(curr->marked), nullptr); //logical "lazy" remove
                atomic_store(&(pred->next), curr->next) //physically remove
                (curr->mtx).unlock();
                (pred->mtx).unlock();
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            //## unlock and loop again ##
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
bool LazySet<T>::contains(const T& k) const {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> curr;
    curr = atomic_load(&(head->next));
    //Find window where key should be in sorted list
    while ((curr) && (curr->key < k)) {
        curr = atomic_load(&(curr->next));
    }
    //Check if key exists in window
    if (curr) {
        if (curr->key == k) { //key exists, unless marked
            return (atomic_load(&(curr->marked)) != nullptr);
        } else { //doesn't exist
            return false;
        }
    } else { //doesn't exist
        return false;
    }
}
```

`Node.marked` was originally a plain bool, and `LazySet.counter` didn't exist. The choice to make them shared_ptrs was to be able to be able to atomically modify both a counter on the number of nodes and the lazy removal mark on the nodes. Modifying both simultaneously in `remove()` is necessary for `is_empty()` to be linearizable with `contains()`. (It can't be a separate bool mark and int counter without a double wide CAS or something.) I hope to implement the counter with shared_ptr's  `use_count()` function, but in multithreaded contexts it's only an approximation due to `relaxed_memory_order`.

I know standalone fences are usually bad practice, and I'm not too familiar with using them. **But if I implemented `is_empty` like below, would the fences ensure it's no longer an approximation, but an exact value for a reliable counter?**

```cpp
template <class T>
bool LazySet<T>::is_empty() const {
    // ## SOME FULL MEMORY BARRIER
    if (counter.use_count() == 1) {
        // ## SOME FULL MEMORY BARRIER
        return true
    }
    // ## SOME FULL MEMORY BARRIER
    return false
}
```

I only ask because [LWG Issue 2776](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2776) says:

> We can't make  `use_count()`  reliable without adding substantially more fencing.

Comment: For those of us that don't have [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0123973376/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_Vw26Cb97AFD2W), can you expand what you mean by "lazy synchronized"?  As you likely know, it's nearly impossible to have a counter method on a collection be both thread safe and meaningful upon return.  What edge and race conditions can you tolerate?

Comment: Overall, between the use of a `shared_ptr<bool>` as a fancy `atomic<int>`, and the fact that every linked list node needs its own `mutex` for some reason, I would say that your implementation of this algorithm is just wrongheaded.

Comment: @selbie Lazy-synchronized is the two step deletion process: first you mark it as removed, then you physically remove it. This allows ```contains``` to be wait-free. Locked nodes can still be traversed, just not modified, and contains doesn't have to wait on remove.

Comment: @NicolBolas So the ```shared_ptr<bool>``` was a janky modification I was considering in order to support ```is_empty()```. The original algorithm with a standard ```bool``` for marked for each node is most definitely correct. One mutex per node is relatively common in hand-over-hand locking type algorithms. This algorithm is an optimization on those. The algorithm can be viewed on [this MIT site](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.852/08/papers/lists-book-chapter.pdf) on page 261.

Comment: is_empty is simply not a meaningful question to ask about a distributed set in a multiprocessor environment. No amount of C++ wizardry can change that.

Comment: I don't disagree, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't/can't be implemented. Java's ConcurrentSkipListSet implements it. 
Edit: Now that's obviously much easier b/c of the structure of a skip list.

Comment: @selbie Sorry, just remembered you asked, my comment on the other answer addresses race and edge conditions.

Comment: Java is not a shiny example of impeccable design. It has to implement isEmpty because it's a Collection, full stop. How meaningful that isEmpty is a different question.

Comment: I agree that is_empty is typically implemented for static sets, not sets that can dynamically change. I had hoped to implement union, subset, etc. So is empty seemed useful for checking the results of that. But I'll prob implement those as members of a static set class that consumes this one or something.

Comment: What the heck is a "correct" refcount value? IOW what incorrect values are benign?

Comment: That's the motivation for the question. What is considered correct by ```use_count()```? I know ```use_count()``` can say 1 while another pointer has been reset or reassigned, but still has pending operations. Because the refcount has relaxed ordering, the meaning of "correct" is less strict than a sequentially consistent counter (specifically SC w/o Race that C++ uses). In general, SC can be combined with serializability to form linearizability. So can you enforce a stricter memory order to allow the system as a whole to be "correct"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
// ## SOME FULL MEMORY BARRIER
if (counter.use_count() == 1) {
    // ## SOME FULL MEMORY BARRIER
```

With an acquire fence before, you can make sure you can make sure you "see" the results of all the resets (including during assignment and destruction) of all owners in other threads. The acquire fence gives all following relaxed operation acquire semantics, preventing them from "fetching values in the future" (which is semantic insanity in any case and probably makes all programs formally UB).

(There is no meaningful fence that you could put after the call.)

Answer (score 1):

Relaxed memory order isn't the problem here. `use_count` is not "reliable" because, by the time the value has been returned, it may have *changed*. There is no data race on getting the value itself, but there's nothing preventing that value from being modified before any conditional statement based on that value.

So you can't do anything with it which relies on its value still being meaningful (with the exception that, if you're still holding a `shared_ptr` instance, then the use count won't go to 0). The only way to make it reliable is to prevent it from being changed. So you'd need to have a mutex.

And that mutex would have to lock, not just around the `use_count` call and usage, but also every time you hand out one of these `shared_ptr`s that you're getting the `use_count` from.

Comment: Comments on this post have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194141/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-nicol-bolas).